# How to redirect user after submitting an article?

Tags: forms, 8, redirection

In Drupal 8 I would like to redirect users to the frontpage and display a status message after submitting an article?

How can I do that? form_alter and custom submit handler?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, form_alter and a custom submit handler was the solution.

```
function _custom_admin_form_node_article_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
    if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
      $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = '_custom_admin_article_form_submit';
    }
  }
}

function _custom_admin_article_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  drupal_set_message(t('Thank you for submitting an article.'));

  $url = Url::fromRoute('<front>');
  $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
}
```

Comment: Note that just adding a drupal_set_message() duplicates the one from core and you have two messages. Getting rid of that requires messing with where they are stored ($_SESSION). Also, you can do $form_state->setRedirect('<front>'), has the same arguments as fromRoute().